# new_path after inputting featured attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Upon a user submitting a `challenge.name` how to direct him to a form where he can finish inputting the object attributes?

**challenges_controller**

```
#user chooses featured challenge.name or creates custom challenge.name
  def featured
    @challenge = Challenge.new
  end

#If user created a custom challenge.name how to redirect him to "def new" to fill out the rest of the challenge's attributes
  def new
    @challenge = Challenge.new
    @challenge.name = challenge_params[:name]
    if @challenge.name == 'Journal'
      @challenge.category = 'habit'
    elsif @challenge.name == 'Meditate'
      @challenge.category = 'habit'
    elsif @challenge.name == 'Run a Mile'
      @challenge.category = 'habit'
    else
      @challenge.category = 'goal'
    end
  end

  def create
    @challenge = Challenge.new(challenge_params)
    @challenge.save
    redirect_to @challenge
  end
```

**challenges/featured.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name,'Enter Custom Challenge' %>
    Or choose a featured challenge:
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Journal') %>
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Meditate') %>
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Run a Mile') %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**challenges/new**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@challenge)  do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.radio_button :category, 'goal', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
  <label for="challenge_category_goal">Goal</label>

  <%= f.radio_button :category, 'habit', class: 'date-format-switcher' %>
  <label for="challenge_category_habit">Habit</label>

  etc....
```

Comment: what do you mean by challenge.name?

Comment: also tell me how create path works

Comment: `.name` is the attribute to challenge @coderVishal. A user can write in a custom `.name` for their challenge in the `text_field`. I want that to pass from the featured form to the new one. I updated question with create action :]

Comment: to send information from a form to a controller action you need to have a submit button.

Comment: I have a submit button. Sorry added that to question @coderVishal

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com You need to specify the form url, and set it to the new_challenge_path and set the method to `GET`. Thought i won't recommend you doing what you are doing.

Comment: Sorry @Alfie I'm confused. Are you proposing a workaround if so can you explain in an answer?

Comment: first can you confirm this is what you want:  Render the featured.html form. Then if the user selects a New Challenge, or enters a new challenge and submits the form take him to the challenges/new form ?

Comment: Yes exactly @Alfie :]

Comment: A suggestion: why not have two actions `featured_new` and `featured_create`. You can post the form to `featured_create` and render `new` from there.

Comment: Consider using wicked gem https://github.com/schneems/wicked, especially if you plan on adding more steps in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= simple_form_for @challenge, url: new_challenge_path, method: 'GET' do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name,'Enter Custom Challenge' %>
    Or choose a featured challenge:
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Journal') %>
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Meditate') %>
  <%= link_to 'New Challenge', new_challenge_path(name: 'Run a Mile') %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Can you please give this a try

Comment: Yeah, as expected. it's because it's the GET method used. You'll have to have another action to which you can post and then take it from there to new.